# Add summary or vendorextensions to Paths in swagger using swashbuckle

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

As per [openApi Spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/)

> Paths may have an optional short summary and a longer description for documentation purposes. This information is supposed to be relevant to all operations in this path. description can be multi-line and supports Markdown (CommonMark) for rich text representation.

I am using [swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to generate swagger UI and doc for my APIs. I need to add summary and some custom fields for paths. For operations I can add using IOperationFilter however I didn't find any way to add for Paths. How to add using Swashbuckle?

Comment: Just FYI, Swagger UI [does not display](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5653) path-level summaries and descriptions.

Comment: Yes I know that and that is fine. Just wanted in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to add `summary` with the version you are linking, see the model `PathItem`:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs#L75

```
public class PathItem
{
    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    public string @ref;

    public Operation get;

    public Operation put;

    public Operation post;

    public Operation delete;

    public Operation options;

    public Operation head;

    public Operation patch;

    public IList<Parameter> parameters;

    public Dictionary<string, object> vendorExtensions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

As you can see there is no summary there...

The only option I see for you is to fork the project, then add what you need to that model,
 I started on that same road with swagger-net:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net
many of the features I needed were missing just like what you are suggesting if you can provide more details on what you are trying to achieve I could add that feature on swagger-net

Comment: thanks. I too realized that summary is not possible. Also I didn't find easy way of adding vendor extensions. I took a workaround I used IDocumentFilter traversed through all the paths and added custom fields and values using vendorExtensions.